# Eclipse, how to include dll's with project?

Tags: eclipse, binaries

I only know how to include libs in eclipse, but with API's like irrKlang and SDL you need to have SDL.dll present at all times (or irrKlang.dll) how do you include this in the building of an application?

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the DLL in an eclipse plugin/OSGi bundle?  If so, you can use `Bundle-NativeCode` in your MANIFEST.MF to control the specification of your DLLs (or other OS natives).

```
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/both.dll; osname=win32; processor=x86,
 lib/xp.dll; osname=winxp; processor=x86, lib/vista.dll;
 osname=winvista; processor=x86, lib/libmylib1.so ; lib/libmylib2.so;
 osname=linux; processor=x86
```

A search on `Bundle-NativeCode` will provide a number of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Create your_plugin/os/win32 and put your dlls there. Add os/ folder to build.properties file (bin.includes).